# how to launch a bootnode and necessary parameters

Tags: bootnode

What are the necessary parameters that substrate bootnodes need to configure,  --sync Full --pruning archive --node-key Is it ok?

Other nodes synchronize blocks by linking bootnodes

Answer (score 3):

Bootnodes don't need to be an archive node.

IMO, you just need to make sure that you have a public IP and the `--port` is opening.

---

`--node-key-file`/`--node-key` is optional now.

The node key will be generated automatically when the first boot.

And in the latest Substrate version, the node will store the node key automatically to the `/<path>/chains/network/secret_ed25519`.

---

If you decide to use `--node-key-file`, then `./node --node-key-file <path>`.

If the `<path>` doesn't exist, the node key will be generated automatically.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, bootnodes are only to allow peer discovering right?

Comment: It provides an endpoint, where you could access the whole network. Nodes will exchange their network list when they get connected.